# Item click event of a custom ListView not working in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

We are working on a project where we have a custom listview and a baseadapter.We are trying to get the item click event of the listview.I pasted a toast within the item click listener in the activity and it is not showing.The following is the code that i have done.

```
question_list is the ListView Object.

question_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               // TextView example = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.single_question_name);
              //  String a=example.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"jo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

The data for the listview is added dynamically.We have used two dynamic layouts for inflation in the baseadapter.The code in the baseadapter is as follows:

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<QuestionsDataModel>  question_list_array;
    List<OptionsDataModel> option_list;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    SingleHolder sh;
    int k=0,l=0;
    View v_single=null,v_multiple=null,v_final=null;
    MultipleHolder mh;
    int number_of_options;
    int position_counter=0;
    public  static  final  int TYPE_HEADER=0;
    public  static  final  int TYPE_ROW=1;
    public QuestionAdapter(ArrayList<QuestionsDataModel> question_list_array, Context context) {
        this.question_list_array=question_list_array;
        this.context=context;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return question_list_array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

   @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return 2;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (question_list_array.get(position).getQuestion_type().equals("single"))?TYPE_HEADER :TYPE_ROW;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String question_type = question_list_array.get(position).getQuestion_type();
        option_list = question_list_array.get(position).option_list;
        number_of_options = option_list.size();

        if (question_type.equals("single"))
        {
            v_single=convertView;
            if (v_single == null)
            {
                v_single = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice_layout, null);
                sh = new SingleHolder();
                sh.single_question_name = (TextView) v_single.findViewById(R.id.single_question_name);
                sh.single_radiogroup = (RadioGroup) v_single.findViewById(R.id.single_radiogroup);
                v_single.setTag(sh);
            }
            else
            {
                sh = (SingleHolder) v_single.getTag();
            }
            sh.single_radiogroup.clearCheck();
            sh.single_radiogroup.removeAllViews();
            sh.single_question_name.setText(question_list_array.get(position).getQuestion_name());
            for (int j = 0; j < number_of_options; j++)
            {
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
                rb.setText(option_list.get(j).getOption_name());
                sh.single_radiogroup.addView(rb);
            }

           v_final=v_single;
        }



      else if(question_type.equals("multiple"))
        {

            v_multiple = convertView;
            if (v_multiple == null) {
                v_multiple = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multiple_choice_layout, null);
                mh = new MultipleHolder();
                mh.multiple_question_name = (TextView) v_multiple.findViewById(R.id.multiple_question_name);
                mh.ll_multiple = (LinearLayout) v_multiple.findViewById(R.id.ll_multiple);
                mh.ll_choice_child= (LinearLayout) v_multiple.findViewById(R.id.ll_choice_child);
                v_multiple.setTag(mh);

            } else {
                mh = (MultipleHolder) v_multiple.getTag();
            }
            mh.multiple_question_name.setText(question_list_array.get(position).getQuestion_name());
            mh.ll_choice_child.removeAllViews();
                for (int m = 0; m < number_of_options; m++)
                {
                    CheckBox c = new CheckBox(context);
                    c.setText(option_list.get(m).getOption_name());
                    mh.ll_choice_child.addView(c);
                }


            //return v;
            v_final=v_multiple;

        }
        return v_final;
    }



    private   class SingleHolder
    {
        TextView single_question_name;
        RadioGroup single_radiogroup;

    }
    private  class MultipleHolder
    {
        TextView multiple_question_name;
        LinearLayout ll_multiple;
        LinearLayout ll_choice_child;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I have added the single item xml files:

single_choice_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/single_question_name"
      />
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/single_radiogroup"
        android:orientation="vertical"></RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
```

multiple_choice_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll_multiple"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/multiple_question_name"
        android:text="second question"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll_choice_child"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post the list items xml , may be focusability issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click is not working on the Listitem Listview android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610023/click-is-not-working-on-the-listitem-listview-android)

Comment: The problem is, that You have other focusable views inside the listView (I guess because of Your Adapter code). You have to set the attribute for the listView items android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to get the click event on listView work.

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee i have set android:focusable property to false to child elements of the layout and and also have set the focusable of dynamic views as false and still the problem persists.pls help!!

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886843/listview-onclicklistner-not-working-and-delete-row-from-listview/18887519#18887519

Answer (score 0):

Try defining ClickListener inside onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return position of item of a `Listview`  in `getItem` method of BaseAdaptor

```
 @Override
    public QuestionsDataModel getItem(int position) {
        return question_list_array.get(position);
    }

@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```